# Insertion into multiple tables in sql server via xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xpath, xquery

I want to do inserts into multiple tables, i.e. `Customer, Account, AccountTransactions`

**Edit**

- `Entity - Customer` one to one
- `Customer - Account` is mapped as one to one
- `Account - AccountTransactions` are mapped as one to many

`Entity(EntityId, EntityType)` EntityId primary key Auto incremented

`Customer(CustomerId, FName, LName)`  CustomerId = EntityId primary key

`Account(AccountId, AccountNo, CustomerId)`  AccountId PK, CustomerId FK

`AccountTransactions(TransactionId, PaymentDate, CurrentBalance, AccountId)` TransactionId PK, AccountId FK

My XML is:

```
<CustomerList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
       <Customer>
              <CustomerId/>
              <CustomerName>Abhishek</CustomerName>
              <AccountId/>
              <AccountNumber>eba5d378-b</AccountNumber>
              <Transactions>
                     <Transaction>
                <TransactionId/>
                            <PaymentDate>2/2/2012</PaymentDate>
                            <Amount>500</Amount>
                     </Transaction>
                     <Transaction>
                <TransactionId/>
                            <PaymentDate>2/2/2012</PaymentDate>
                            <Amount>500</Amount>
                     </Transaction>
              </Transactions>
          </Customer>
       <Customer>
              <CustomerId/>
              <CustomerName>Yash</CustomerName>
              <AccountId/>
              <AccountNumber>A101202</AccountNumber>
              <Transactions>
                     <Transaction>
                <TransactionId/>
                            <PaymentDate>2/2/2012</PaymentDate>
                            <Amount>500</Amount>
                     </Transaction>
                     <Transaction>
                <TransactionId/>
                            <PaymentDate>2/2/2012</PaymentDate>
                            <Amount>500</Amount>
                     </Transaction>
              </Transactions>
       </Customer>
</CustomerList>
```

I want to insert into `Customer, Account, Transaction` table for each customer in xml and upon insertion into customer its id should be saved back into xml and also used in `Account` table as a foreign key

I can see only way is to use nested cursor or nested while loop. Do any better method exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the proper tables in place - you can definitely do an iterative approach without any messy kludgy cursor!

Try something like this - this will handle customers and accounts for now, but you can definitely extend this to the transactions, too.

```
declare @input XML = '... your XML here .....';

CREATE TABLE #CustAcct (CustomerName VARCHAR(50), CustomerID INT, AcctNumber VARCHAR(50), AcctID INT);

-- first extract customer and account into from the XML, using a common table expression    
WITH CustomersAndAccounts AS
(
   SELECT
       CustomerName = CL.Cust.value('(CustomerName)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
       AcctNumber = CL.Cust.value('(AccountNumber)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
   FROM 
       @input.nodes('/CustomerList/Customer') CL(Cust)
)
INSERT INTO #CustAcct(CustomerName, AcctNumber)
    SELECT CustomerName, AcctNUmber
    FROM CustomersAndAccounts

-- insert customers into 'Customer' table    
INSERT INTO Customer(CustomerName)
    SELECT CustomerName
    FROM #CustAcct

-- update the temporary working table with the appropriate ID's from the 'Customer' table    
UPDATE #CustAcct
SET CustomerID = c.CustomerID
FROM Customer c
WHERE #CustAcct.CustomerName = c.CustomerName

-- insert values into 'Account' table from the working table   
INSERT INTO Account(CustomerID, AccountNumber)
    SELECT CustomerID, AcctNumber
    FROM #CustAcct

-- update the working table from the values inserted
UPDATE #CustAcct
SET AcctID = a.AccountID
FROM Account a
WHERE #CustAcct.CustomerID = a.CustomerID AND #CustAcct.AcctNumber = a.AccountNumber

SELECT * FROM #CustAcct
```

Now in a next step, you could parse the transaction for each customer/account pair and insert those into the appropriate table.

Comment: I know it could have been done if I had any business primary key. My actual database design somewhat replicates AdventureWorks2008R2 `BusinessEntity(BusinessEntityId, BusinessEntityType)` table where BusinessEntityId is generated at the first place which is then inserted into Person table to create a Person. Thereafter rest of the entities flows. Any idea how to resove this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with the SQLXML Bulkload component:

How to import XML into SQL Server with the XML Bulk Load component
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316005